# How to access hotspot created on Linux (ubuntu/mint etc) from android device?

Tags: android, linux

I am able to create hotspot(ad-hoc) and it is visible to other laptops and connects successfully but hotspot is not visible to android app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/), you can't use ad-hoc with an android device